# web app losing credentials when calling database

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis, iis-7

I have a Web server and a separate database server.  This is an internal web page only so is not on an external DMZ.  IIS Settings for the web site authentication are Anonymous Disables, ASP.Net enabled, forms disabled, windows enabled.

If I get the current user name using the below code on the web page it renders correctly from the client machine:

```
lblUserName.Text = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString()
```

When I run the web site locally on the web server the database connection works perfectly, but when I run from the client machine for some reason it loses the current user and tries to use anonymous credentials to connect rather than passing through the current windows credentials.  The error message presented is: Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'. (when making the DB connection).

My DB connection string is set in web.config and has Integrated Security="SSPI".  In my web.config I also have authentication mode="windows" and identity impersonate = "true".

Not sure if it makes a difference (I am not great at IIS, having usually had someone else in the company deal with this, and where I am now there is no-one who really seems to know what they are doing with IIS) but in IIS on the App Pool I have the advanced settings process model identity set to 'ApplicationPoolIdentity' and load user profile set to True.  I have also tried, on advice from Tim (thank you), using a known used instead of the ApplicationPoolIdentity, and have entered the credentials used to run the SSRS reports so I know they have the right permissions, but still get the same error.

Am I missing something really obvious in IIS or in the web.config which is needed to pass through the current user credentials?

Comment: You either need to set the app pool in IIS to run under an account that has permissions to log-in to the SQL server, or pass a user name and password in your configuration file.  I'd suggest the former.

Comment: Ok, thank you.  I was really hoping to use the windows credentials so that I could capture which user was calling what in the DB level but I will look at other ways to achieve this.

Comment: I have set this app pool identity to a user with access but I still get the error at the client computer of the web app trying an anonymous logon.

Comment: exact error: Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'. (now added to OP)